# Using tail -F to see a file changing in real-time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tail

I have a script that collects the size of a file that is being constantly fed. I'm echoing its size to a log file (echo 'filesize is $size' > log.txt) so I only have the last size information. So, only one line.

Now, in another terminal, I wanted to tail that log file to see its size increasing in real time. It turns out, tail -f path/to/file gives me the output I want but it keeps jumping to the next line (as expected, I guess).

So, the output is something like:

```
$ tail -F log.txt 2>/dev/null
filesize is 1.658 GB
filesize is 1.659 GB
filesize is 1.659 GB
filesize is 1.660 GB
```

I wanted something more like the command "less" in which you don't have the cursor back. Maybe a better example would be "mtr", that keeps updating the information on the screen without going to next line (as opposed to traceroute).

Thank you,

Comment: If you just want to monitor the file size then try `watch du -skh filename`.

Comment: Though this a well explored question, `StackOverflow` community is _solving problems programmatically_ and request for general software utilities tools are more relevant at http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Inian questions about Bash and shell programming are perfectly on-topic on Stack Overflow. Even for ones that aren't, unix.stackexchange.com is the better place to redirect people.

Comment: @ASR, it works great, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; clear; tail log.txt; done
```

This does not have the drawback of passing command and arguments to `watch` (sometimes you need to hop extra loops to make it correctly), and it clears the terminal.

Comment: that's very interesting, using the clear gives the impression the screen around the updated area is not changing. Even though, you could scroll up and see the content repeating, it's very practical. Thanks,

Answer (score 11):

Use this command.

```
watch tail -n 1 log.txt
```

Comment: What will that do exactly? Man page says "`-n number` The location is `number` lines"

Comment: `tail -n 1` shows you the last line of a file, `watch tail -n 1` shows you the last line of the file every 2 seconds, and clears the screen before doing so

Answer (score 5):

You can [`watch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) command to monitor the file changes/difference (`-d`) every `n` seconds

```
watch -n 5 -d cat log.txt
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me.  I am getting `log.txt - command not found` error.

Comment: Pretty sure this doesn't work - you still need to run a command.

Comment: `watch -n 5 -d cat log.txt`

Comment: Hmm.  `"$(<log.txt)"` interprets the content of the file as commands.

Comment: @codeforester: seems `cat` is useful for once, thanks!

Comment: But wouldn't that defeat the purpose?  It would show the whole file again!

Comment: You don't need `-d`, just `watch tail -n 1 log.txt`

Comment: No the `-d` flag just prints the difference!

Comment: `-d` does not show only the differences, it highlights the differences, usually by using the ASNI control codes for italics

Comment: @OregonTrail: Quoting from the `man` page, `The -d or --differences flag will highlight the differences between successive updates.`

Comment: right, it will highlight them, but not show only the differences. run this command and edit log.txt and observe for yourself

Comment: But that is what OP wants, he hasn't stated a case of unwanted "write" operations in the middle. Appreciate what you are getting at!

Comment: For those who said "watch -n 5 -d cat log.txt" didn't work, it worked fine for me on Ubuntu Xenial.

Comment: @Adriano_epifas : You can click on the small tick on the left of the answer to mark it _accepted_ and working!

Comment: @Inian, right. Had forgotten it. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

The fanciest solution to receive realtime information on a file  ist to use inotify

Which is a linux kernel feature to receive notification when a specific file changes. You can either write your own c program which uses the functionality or you simply build a script with the inotify-wait or inotify-watch command. You probably need to install it though. But both are well documented. 
New versions of tail also use this linux kernel functionality

EDIT: keep in mind that this only helps you with monitoring file events. What you do when such an event occours is not my cup of tea.

PS. Have you considered that the process that writes the file MAYBE only flushes its writing buffer when a line break is present